# Variable content in random order

Tags: php

I want content of this PHP variable to come into random order each time page is refreshed or visited.

Such as

```
$test = 'a, b, c, d, e, f';
```

I want best way to get it randomly, example

```
$test = 'c, b, d, f, a, e';

$test = 'd, e, c, a, f, b';
```

Any solution?

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself?

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Comment: @Paul there are much easier ways than with `rand()`. Array to `shuffle()` is where I'd start...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest something like this:

```
$content = 'a, b, c, d, e, f';
$content = explode(', ', $content);

shuffle($content);

$content = implode(', ', $content);

echo $content;
```

---

What this code does:

- [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) makes an array with items like `a`, `b`, `c` ect.
- [`shuffle`](http://php.net/shuffle) shuffles the array
- [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) put a `,`  between each item, so we get the origional randomized string back

Answer (score 6):

```
$test = 'a, b, c, d, e, f';
$testArray = explode(', ',$test); //explode to array

shuffle($testArray); //shuffle it up

echo implode(', ', $testArray); //show the shuffledlyness
```